# How to set timer for downloading file in android?

Tags: android, timer, alarmmanager, android-sqlite

My Aim is to set a timer for synchronization. I want after 15 minutes timer start synchronization with method that I will create. But I need to add entry into the database, so that timer should start automatically. I am new to it, So I am confused which task will take place first. Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: Use alarm manager and set repeat alarm time. There's a method for repetitive alarms.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16128091/setting-up-alarm-manager-is-creating-2-instances-of-my-main-activity/16134932#16134932

Answer (score 0):

use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) in this case. [Here](http://code4reference.com/2012/07/tutorial-on-android-alarmmanager/) you can find a nice tutorial about `AlarmManager` to fullfill your goal